# Is it possible to play in the middle of nowhere?

Tags: watch-dogs-live

The [Watch Dogs Live ARG app](http://www.watchdogslive.ca/) here in Canada is about some kind of arbitrary hacking of locations or so it seems, but I wouldn't know because there are never any locations for me to hack. I'd love to participate, but see no way of doing this after selecting hack. Am I being punished for living in the boonies? Is this dependent upon proximity to some specific people or places in particular? I thought the instructions seemed pretty straightforward, but am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From official [FAQ](http://www.watchdogslive.ca/uploads/faq/FAQ-EN.pdf):

> Q: There aren’t any locations displayed on my map for  me to hack. A:
>   There are more locations available to hack in larger  cities. The
>   numbers of locations vary depending on  population density in order to
>   offer a more balanced  game experience. Also, the more new players
>   join the  experience, the more categories of locations will be  added.
>   So, keep moving around until you see locations  appear within the blue
>   radius on your map and invite your  friends to play as well!

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not finding that. The FAQ link in the top-left of their page is terribly small. It's disappointing that they punish me for where I live. Indeed, as I zoom out to 300-400 km, I start seeing a few hack spots in much larger centers. Somehow, even if I had the option of hacking, I still doubt the radius could be improved *that* much.